# Confusion about two-force members

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, free-body-diagram, statics

This is my first question here so I hope I get warmly welcomed by answers that would resolve this perplexion :-)

This is a statics problem from Hibbeler's Mechanics for Engineers: Statics (13th Edition)...
I have access to its solution from the solution manual, but there is something I don't understand here:

[image: Problem]

1. How is AC here a two-force member (as the ISM says) when it has that 2-kN load acting on it at pin A?
2. When AC is a two-force member, Ax = Cx, and Ay = Cy, then the FBD of member AC would have only the reaction forces at the two pins A and C, how is it that the 2-kN force is not considered here?

I know both questions seem quite similar, but this is for the purpose of clarification as to where the confusion lies.

Comment: I wouldn't get hung up on someone else's artificial classification of the problem.  I hadn't hear the term "two force member" before, but what does that matter anyway?  I don't know what the problem is asking for, but it is easily possible to solve for the forces on the pins, force on member A-C, force on the bottom support, etc.  If you're stuck solving this problem, ask about that specifically.

Comment: Well, a two-force member is any structure that has only two forces acting on it. In equilibrium, these forces must be equal, opposite, and collinear... (You could've looked that up)...Anyway, my question is: how would you draw the FBD of member AC? And why would you draw it that way? My question is not on the whole problem but just to clear some misconception that I might have here :)

Comment: It should be obvious that A-C only has two forces on it (other than gravity, since weights weren't given I'm assuming you're supposed to ignore this).  It is in compression, so the pin at each end is pushing on the member in the direction of the other pin.  Since A-C isn't accellerating, those two forces are equal and opposite.  What's the problem?

Comment: Can I consider that 2-kN load to be acting on pin A, and hence have a component acting on AC? This way AC wouldn't have only two forces acting on it...If no, then why not?

Comment: I though you weren't interested in the actual solution, but the semantics of "two force member".  If you want help with the solution, ask about that.

Comment: I'm struggling to tell you my question but you're not getting it at all...
I don't bother about semantics or shit, the question is clear: you say only two forces act on AC, that is the reactions of the pins, but I'm asking why not consider the 2-kN force at A and say that three forces actually act on beam AC?

If you can't answer my question, then please don't bug me and let those who can do it answer me

Comment: If that's what you want to know, then again, *ask about that*.  Your question as it currently stands is all hung up about whether A-C is a "two force" member or not.  Write the question properly about what the forces are at pin A or on member A-C, if that's what you really want to know.  You also seem to be misreading the diagram, or at least jumping to a incorrect conclusion.

Comment: @user101197 Counting forces acting on some object is a somewhat futile attempt (of course counting the number of point forces can act on is reasonable). Also, there is no need to lash out against Olin Lanthrop, your question is not only unclear, but also at least borderline off-topic (as it is about the solution of statics homework and vocabulary from engineering).

Comment: Well my question is clear I don't know what's wrong with you: " then the FBD of member AC would have only the reaction forces at the two pins A and C, how is it that the 2-kN force is not considered here?" " when it has that 2-kN load acting on it at pin A?"...if you don't understand that then it's not my problem...Plus the question fits well here provided there is no special stack exchange site for mechanics, it fits well too in the two sites you mentioned but it's not offtopic here

Comment: "Your question as it currently stands is all hung up about whether A-C is a "two force" member or not.  Write the question properly about what the forces are at pin A or on member A-C, if that's what you really want to know."...Again my question was why this beam is subjected to two forces, not whether it's two-force or not...I've written my question in two "forms", if you don't read the question well and rush to comment then it's your problem

Comment: @user101197 You might want to read our [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have Four equal forces on link AB. There is no any other external force on any of the other links. All other members will bear the forces produced as a result of these forces. I don't know what makes you think that the 2kN force on AB is acting on AC. It is clearly visible that the 2kN force is on AB not on pin AC.